# Custom Navigation Bar, button inside UIView .xib does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I have a UIView .xib inside a UIViewController .xib

inside the UIView file I have a button and clicking it should lead to another ViewController, but it doesn't, just a test print I added works.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class CustomNavigationBar: UIView {

let nav = UINavigationController()
let detailVC = AlertViewController()

@IBAction func buttonNavBar2(_ sender: UIButton) {

    nav.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
        
        print("BUTTON ALERT")
    }

}
```

even so it doesn't work:

```
import Foundation
    import UIKit
    
    final class CustomNavigationBar: UIView {
    
    let nav = FirstViewController()
    let detailVC = AlertViewController()
    
    @IBAction func buttonNavBar2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
        nav.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
            
            print("BUTTON ALERT")
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify controller from which you want to open new controller. Something like this:

`yourViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)`

Comment: divya suthar
that doesn't work either

Comment: Your current view controller has navigation controller right? Because we can push view controller only if the current view controller has navigation controller attached.